# Windows Form button using clip.exe works once and stops

Tags: winforms, powershell

Here is a basic windows form with couple buttons that are supposed to copy to clickboard whatever is in the variable whenever clicked on, it works one time and then the buttons stops responding, any idea why?

The code is :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Click2Copy :)"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font ("Roman", 11, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.AutoSize = $false
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Form.MinimizeBox = $false
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$Form.Opacity = 0.8
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.BackColor = "black"

#$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
#$label.Location = New-Object Drawing.point 30,100
#$Label.Text = "Click a button to copy its content"
#$Label.AutoSize = $true
#$Label.ForeColor = "White"

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.text = "Server-One-Example"
$button.ForeColor = "White"
$button.AutoSize = $true
$button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 65,10

$copy1 = "Server-One-Example" | clip.exe
$button.Add_Click($copy1)

$button2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.text = "Server-Two-Example"
$button2.ForeColor = "White"
$button2.AutoSize = $true
$button2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 65,40

$copy2 = "Server-Two-Example" | clip.exe
$button2.Add_Click($copy2)

#$Form.controls.add($label)
$form.controls.add($button)
$form.controls.add($button2)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: If you'll do a bit of experimenting, you'll find that with the code as it is here, clicking the buttons does absolutely nothing.  Put "asdf" on your clipboard and then run your program and don't click on anything.  Now paste from the clipboard into Notepad and you'll see it has "Server-Two-Example" on it.  The lines that run pipe output to clip.exe run when the program is run--they are not "wired" to the button click events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines `$copy1 = "Server-One-Example" | clip.exe` and ``$copy2 = "Server-Two-Example"' executing and sending the data to the clipboard when Powershell executes the script.  Accordingly, when the program is run, it sends "Server-One-Example" to the clipboard and then sends "Server-Two-Example" to the clipboard before the user even has a chance to click the button.

The code that you want to run when the button is clicked need to be passed to the Add_Click.  The way you have it $copy1 and $copy2 don't end up containing anything, so the click event doesn't do anything.  To prove this, run `$copy1 = "asdf" | clip.exe` at the PowerShell command prompt.  Then explore the $copy1 variable to see if you can get anything out of it.  `$copy1.ToString()` and `$copy1.GetType()` return errors.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Click2Copy :)"
$Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font ("Roman", 11, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.Font = $Font
$Form.AutoSize = $false
$Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
$Form.MinimizeBox = $false
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.SizeGripStyle = "Hide"
$Form.ShowInTaskbar = $false
$Form.Opacity = 0.8
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.BackColor = "black"

#$Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
#$label.Location = New-Object Drawing.point 30,100
#$Label.Text = "Click a button to copy its content"
#$Label.AutoSize = $true
#$Label.ForeColor = "White"

$button = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button.text = "Server-One-Example"
$button.ForeColor = "White"
$button.AutoSize = $true
$button.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 65,10


$button.Add_Click({"Server-One-Example" | clip.exe})

$button2 = New-Object Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.text = "Server-Two-Example"
$button2.ForeColor = "White"
$button2.AutoSize = $true
$button2.Location = New-Object Drawing.Point 65,40


$button2.Add_Click({"Server-Two-Example" | clip.exe})

#$Form.controls.add($label)
$form.controls.add($button)
$form.controls.add($button2)
$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thank you! so if I understand correctly you removed the variables, used set strings instead and added {} before ()? One quick question regarding the same script, when calling it from a batch file the windows form opens but with the powershell window in the background, is there a way to only make the windows form be visible? i don't have a -noexit in the bat or anything.

Comment: I just removed the lines that (tried to) set `$copy1` and `$copy2`, and changed the Add_Click methods to include the code you want to run.

Comment: `powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -f c:\temp\test.ps1`

Comment: marked as answer, not enough rep to upvote yet sorry :)